# Received AliveMessage from a peer with the same PKI-ID as myself

Tags: kubernetes, hyperledger-fabric

I am attempting to port the Hyperledger Fabric Getting Started to Kubernetes. But am struggling to get `peer1`'s to deploy. If I enable `CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP`, I receive errors "Received AliveMessage from a peer with the same PKI-ID as myself".

How can I debug a peer reportedly having the same PKI-ID as another?

Using this as a starting point:

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html

I am able to create:

- `orderer` and `cli` pods in `default` namespace
- `peer0`'s one in each `org1`|`org2` namespace.
- `peer1`'s but only if I disable (comment out) `CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP`

If I enable `CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP` for the `peer1`'s, I receive the following warning and error:

```
[gossip/gossip#10.0.0.10:7051] NewGossipService -> WARN 01c External endpoint is empty, peer will not be accessible outside of its organization
...
[gossip/discovery#10.0.0.10:7051] handleAliveMessage -> ERRO 02a Bad configuration detected: Received AliveMessage from a peer with the same PKI-ID as myself: tag:EMPTY alive_msg:<membership:<pki_id:"[[REDACTED]]" > timestamp:<inc_number:1495468533769417608 seq_num:416 > >
```

In order to better map the `Orderer`, `Peers` to DNS names, I'm using Kubernetes Namespaces and this configuration:

```
OrdererOrgs:
  - Name: Orderer
    Domain: default.svc.cluster.local
    Specs:
      - Hostname: orderer
PeerOrgs:
  - Name: Org1
    Domain: org1.svc.cluster.local
    Template:
      Count: 2
    Users:
      Count: 2
  - Name: Org2
    Domain: org2.svc.cluster.local
    Template:
      Count: 2
    Users:
      Count: 2
```

In order to expose the `peer0`'s to the other peers in the org and to expose the `orderer`, I have `ClusterIP` services for the `peer0`'s (selecting only the `peer0`'s) and `orderer`. It's inelegant but I'm trying to get it to work before I get it working more beautifully.

I am able to resolve `orderer.default.svc.cluster.local`,  `peer0.org1.svc.cluster.local`, `peer0.org2.svc.cluster.local' using nslookup from within a pod deployed to default on the cluster.

Absent a curl-like tool for gPRC, I am able to open sockets against these endpoints on `7051` and `7053`.

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure you are using the right certificates.
Second, verify that your environment/configuration for `gossip` is set correctly

```
environment:
  - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer1.org1.example.com:8051
  - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
  - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ENDPOINT=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
```

OR in core.yaml

```
peer:
  gossip:
    bootstrap: peer0.org1.example.com:7051
    externalEndpoint: peer1.org1.example.com:8051
    endpoint: peer0.org1.example.com:7051
```

Edited: Also make sure that you have properly setup your [CA](https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/users-guide.html#getting-started)

Hope this helps, it worked for me. And I was successfully able to connect peers.

Answer (score 1):

If the peers are started from the same node, its possible that you are mounting the same crypto-material (path to mspconfig directory) for both the peers. If that is the case, separate the directory structures for both the peers and keep their respective certificates in them, update the respective paths for msp in docker-compose file and try to run.