# Error: Got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST

Tags: kubernetes, hyperledger-fabric

I believe I have an `orderer`, two `peer`'s and a `cli` running on Kubernetes.

Trying to issue `peer` commands within `cli` results in errors.

**Update**: I've tried running the same crypto-config under `docker-compose` and receive the same error from `peer channel create`. This suggests either something is incorrect with my `cli` command or with the crypto-config itself.

I would appreciate some guidance on debugging steps that would help me.

Probably related to the issues summarized in my earlier question:
[Received AliveMessage from a peer with the same PKI-ID as myself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44118305/609290)

Within `cli`:

```
CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="OrdererMSP" \
peer channel create \
--orderer orderer.default.svc.cluster.local:7050 \
--chain ch01 \
--file channel.170511.tx
```

Results in:

```
2017-05-22 17:36:52.235 UTC [logging] InitFromViper -> DEBU 001 Setting default logging level to DEBUG for command 'channel'
2017-05-22 17:36:52.235 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 002 Returning existing local MSP
2017-05-22 17:36:52.236 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 003 Obtaining default signing identity
Error: Got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST
Usage:
  peer channel create [flags]
```

and coincidentally on `orderer`:

```
2017-05-22 17:36:52.326 UTC [orderer/main] Deliver -> DEBU 11f Starting new Deliver handler
2017-05-22 17:36:52.326 UTC [orderer/common/deliver] Handle -> DEBU 120 Starting new deliver loop
2017-05-22 17:36:52.326 UTC [orderer/common/deliver] Handle -> DEBU 121 Attempting to read seek info message
2017-05-22 17:36:52.332 UTC [orderer/main] Broadcast -> DEBU 122 Starting new Broadcast handler
2017-05-22 17:36:52.333 UTC [orderer/common/broadcast] Handle -> DEBU 123 Preprocessing CONFIG_UPDATE
2017-05-22 17:36:52.333 UTC [orderer/multichain] Process -> DEBU 124 Processing channel creation request for channel ch01
2017-05-22 17:36:52.333 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 125 Returning existing local MSP
2017-05-22 17:36:52.333 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 126 Obtaining default signing identity
2017-05-22 17:36:52.333 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 127 Returning existing local MSP
2017-05-22 17:36:52.333 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 128 Obtaining default signing identity
2017-05-22 17:36:52.333 UTC [msp] Sign -> DEBU 129 Sign: plaintext: [[REDACTED]]...[[REDACTED]] 
2017-05-22 17:36:52.333 UTC [msp] Sign -> DEBU 12a Sign: digest: [[REDACTED]] 
2017-05-22 17:36:52.333 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 12b Returning existing local MSP
2017-05-22 17:36:52.333 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 12c Obtaining default signing identity
2017-05-22 17:36:52.333 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 12d Returning existing local MSP
2017-05-22 17:36:52.333 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 12e Obtaining default signing identity
2017-05-22 17:36:52.333 UTC [msp] Sign -> DEBU 12f Sign: plaintext: [[REDACTED]]...[[REDACTED]] 
2017-05-22 17:36:52.333 UTC [msp] Sign -> DEBU 130 Sign: digest: [[REDACTED]] 
2017-05-22 17:36:52.334 UTC [orderer/common/broadcast] Handle -> DEBU 131 Broadcast is filtering message of type 4 for channel testchainid
2017-05-22 17:36:52.334 UTC [common/policies] GetPolicy -> DEBU 132 Returning policy Writers for evaluation
2017-05-22 17:36:52.334 UTC [cauthdsl] func1 -> DEBU 133 Gate evaluation starts: (&{N:1 policies:<signed_by:0 > })
2017-05-22 17:36:52.334 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 134 Principal evaluation starts: (&{%!s(int32=0)}) (used [%!s(bool=false)])
2017-05-22 17:36:52.334 UTC [msp] newIdentity -> DEBU 135 Creating identity instance for ID &{OrdererMSP DEFAULT}
2017-05-22 17:36:52.334 UTC [msp] Validate -> INFO 136 MSP OrdererMSP validating identity
2017-05-22 17:36:52.334 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 137 Principal evaluation fails: (&{%!s(int32=0)})%!(EXTRA []bool=[false])
2017-05-22 17:36:52.334 UTC [cauthdsl] func1 -> DEBU 138 Gate evaluation fails: (&{N:1 policies:<signed_by:0 > })
2017-05-22 17:36:52.334 UTC [cauthdsl] func1 -> DEBU 139 Gate evaluation starts: (&{N:1 policies:<signed_by:0 > })
2017-05-22 17:36:52.334 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 13a Principal evaluation starts: (&{%!s(int32=0)}) (used [%!s(bool=false)])
2017-05-22 17:36:52.334 UTC [msp] newIdentity -> DEBU 13b Creating identity instance for ID &{OrdererMSP DEFAULT}
2017-05-22 17:36:52.334 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 13c Principal evaluation fails: (&{%!s(int32=0)})%!(EXTRA []bool=[false])
2017-05-22 17:36:52.334 UTC [cauthdsl] func1 -> DEBU 13d Gate evaluation fails: (&{N:1 policies:<signed_by:0 > })
2017-05-22 17:36:52.334 UTC [cauthdsl] func1 -> DEBU 13e Gate evaluation starts: (&{N:1 policies:<signed_by:0 > })
2017-05-22 17:36:52.334 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 13f Principal evaluation starts: (&{%!s(int32=0)}) (used [%!s(bool=false)])
2017-05-22 17:36:52.334 UTC [msp] newIdentity -> DEBU 140 Creating identity instance for ID &{OrdererMSP DEFAULT}
2017-05-22 17:36:52.334 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 141 Principal evaluation fails: (&{%!s(int32=0)})%!(EXTRA []bool=[false])
2017-05-22 17:36:52.334 UTC [cauthdsl] func1 -> DEBU 142 Gate evaluation fails: (&{N:1 policies:<signed_by:0 > })
2017-05-22 17:36:52.334 UTC [orderer/common/broadcast] Handle -> WARN 143 Rejecting broadcast message because of filter error: Rejected by rule: *sigfilter.sigFilter
2017-05-22 17:36:52.336 UTC [orderer/common/deliver] Handle -> WARN 144 Error reading from stream: stream error: code = 1 desc = "context canceled"
```

crypto-config:

```
OrdererOrgs:
  - Name: Orderer
    Domain: default.svc.cluster.local
    Specs:
      - Hostname: orderer
PeerOrgs:
  - Name: Org1
    Domain: org1.svc.cluster.local
    Template:
      Count: 2
    Users:
      Count: 2
  - Name: Org2
    Domain: org2.svc.cluster.local
    Template:
      Count: 2
    Users:
      Count: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Please keep the channel name all small case only. This solved the problem for me.

Before creating the channel artifact set the channel name to small letters like below:
    export CHANNEL_NAME=casesensitivechannelname

Use the same channel name while creating channel.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you haven't especified well the MSP directory and the MSP identities.

The CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH should coincide with your certificates directories. As the same as the CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID. In my opinios, that is the issue.

Make sure that the configuration of the crypto-config file, the configtx file and the docker-compose file coincide.

- When you execute the cryptogen tool, it creates you a directories tree with all the certificates that you need. It follows the Domain and Host that you define in this file.
- When you execute the configtxgen tool, you define the MSP directory for each organization.
- Finally, in the docker-compose file you also define the MSP ID and the directories for the MSP config path.

In your case, you define it here:

```
CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="OrdererMSP"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "peer channel list" to see a list of existing channels. You cannot create a new channel with the same name as existing channels.